# Save byte array of image in a folder c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, image, byte

I am converting image name to byte array and i want to save that byte array in a folder 
here is my code to convert byte array

```
 byte[] imgArray = obj.Image.ToByteArray();
```

where obj.image=image(1).jpg. which is of string type.

and I want to save it in my project folder **"Images"**
so how can i do it after converting that image file to byte array.
please give me some idea to do that

here is my project folder where i want to save the file.
**D:\Gaurav\VerveLogicTfs\LogoProject\ProfilePic**

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "image1.jpg"), imgArray);`?

Comment: sir your solution is good but i want to save in in this folder
@"D:\Gaurav\VerveLogicTfs\LogoProject\ProfilePic

Comment: _"where obj.image=image(1).jpg. which is of string type"_ - That means `obj.Image.ToByteArray()` will give you the byte array of that _string_ not the image itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
string filePath = "~/ProfilePic/" + obj.image.ToString();
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), imgArray);
```